# iOS app behaving differently on iOS 7.0 device when created by xcode 4.6 versus xcode 5.0

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, jenkins, ios7

I have an iOS based application for which i create builds using XCode and Jenkins(for providing to testers).

Now what has happened is when i create build using Xcode 4.6 and install on iOS 7.0 based Device(iPhone 5) it works fine without any issues related to status bars and other issue specific to iOS 7.0. And all the views/components are iOS 6 style (prior to iOS 7)

Versus :

When i build it from Xcode 5.0 , and install on iOS 7.0 iPhone 5, the app comes up with all the issues related to iOS 7.0, like the famous status bar overlap issue and picker view gone transparent (new one).

So can any one explain whats going on ?
(as per my knowledge , app should behave same on iOS 7.0 device no matter its created by Xcode 4.6 or Xcode 5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build with Xcode 4.6 you are using iOS SDK 6 and on iOS 6 and 7 application looks identical.

Building with Xcode 5.0 you are using iOS SDK 7 and app on iOS 7 looks differently because of changes in UIKit.

Comment: Why would a picker view look like iOS 6.0 style on iOS 7 device ?

Comment: All apps with a Base SDK of iOS 6 or earlier will keep the old look when run under iOS 7 (except for action sheets and alert views). Apple has no desire to suddenly break 100's of thousands of apps when iOS 7 goes live.

Comment: ok , agreed, but i wanted to understand it logically, like when an app which has some code which calls picker view, should the app not use the device's sdk to display the view (newer one) ?

Comment: Application SDK version is defined when building not in runtime. If you want newer UI , use higher SDK when building your app.

Comment: so, can i submit my application with iOS 6 as base SDK ? or apple doesnt take them after iOS 7.0 release ?

Comment: I think it is still possible to use iOS 6 as base SDK.

Answer (score 0):

There could be few reasons for that:

1. UIKit updates in iOS SDK 7.
2. You use preprocessor directives like #define/#ifdef in which you describe
   UI based on iOS version.
3. Deployment Target is different.